# How to create an IAM Policy for SQS queues for a specific Cognito Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a IAM policy to be applied to a SQS queue. The policy should restrict access to the queue to a single Cognito federated identity.

I found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies/) reference from amazon on how to achieve this but am having trouble applying the policy to the SQS queue.

Here is the policy I am trying to apply.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:604080725100:Test2.fifo/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid1528133390193",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:ff1b33f4-7f66-47a5-b7ff-9696b0e1fb52",
            "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": ["us-east-1:4a6d7e43-4522-41fb-9248-b5b79933b8e9"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The online UI for editing the policy shows in the review screen:

```
Allow   None    
All SQS Actions (SQS:*)
StringEquals
cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud: "us-east-1:ff1b33f4-7f66-47a5-b7ff-9696b0e1fb52"
cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub: "us-east-1:4a6d7e43-4522-41fb-9248-b5b79933b8e9"
```

Once I press apply the following error is given:

```
Failed to save changes to the policy document. Reason: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the policy. I am looking for any help fixing the policy or a different policy that achieve limiting the SQS queue to a single Cognito identity.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQS only supports a [subset of the condition keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-api-permissions-reference.html) and the cognito user id is not one of them. I have read an [article](https://serverless.com/blog/how-reuters-replaced-websockets-with-amazon-cognito-and-sqs/) which solved this problem by creating random queue names which are readable by all users, but practically unguessable.